# MAUI : default child under TabbedPage Object

Tags: maui

I have `TabbedPage` object under which I have several `NavigationPage` objects. Is there any way to set the default page for the `TabbedPage` object so that a specific page is loaded rather than the first item under the `TabbedPage` whenever the page loads.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<NavigationPage Title="Search" >
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:SearchPage Title="Search For Book" />
    </x:Arguments>
    <NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
        <FontImageSource 
     FontFamily="MaterialDesignIconsFonts"
     Glyph="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.Book}"
     Size="25" />
    </NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
    
</NavigationPage>

<NavigationPage  Title="One">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:MainPage Title="One" />
    </x:Arguments>

    <NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
        <FontImageSource 
     FontFamily="MaterialDesignIconsFonts"
     Glyph="{x:Static helpers:MaterialDesignIconsFonts.Menu}"
     Size="25" />
    </NavigationPage.IconImageSource>
    
    
</NavigationPage>
<NavigationPage Title="Two" IconImageSource="{StaticResource TabTwo}">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:NewContextTest Title="Two" />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

Navigation Page has a `CurrentPage` property which is [read only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage). Under the `TabbedPage` [class reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.tabbedpage?view=net-maui-7.0) I could not find any property that resembles default child behaviour.

any help on the matter will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: use the `CurrentPage` property.  You may have to do it from the code behind

Comment: As i said `CurrentPage` is a readonly property. you cannot set it.

Comment: It’s a property of TabbedPage.  [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.multipage-1.currentpage?view=net-maui-7.0#microsoft-maui-controls-multipage-1-currentpage)

Comment: Did you try to set the default page in the App.xaml.cs?